# Workbox service worker with StaleWhileRevalidate

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am facing issue when using 'workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate', i am not getting updated data with response. is there any way to update data with each request using this strategy? I am using broadcastUpdate to check header too but when i login with different terminal it shows old data. I want my indexdb should be update with each request and dom show as per updated response.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('xy/xyzAPI/api'),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'api-url',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 20,
        maxAgeSeconds: 24 * 60 * 60
      }),
      new workbox.broadcastUpdate.Plugin('api-url', {
        headersToCheck: ['date'],
      })
    ]
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

In plugin please remove or decrease workbox expiration

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('xy/xyzAPI/api'),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'api-url',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 20,

      }),
      new workbox.broadcastUpdate.Plugin('api-url', {
        headersToCheck: ['date'],
      })
    ]
  }));
```

Comment: This doen't help. It is not updating cache